# Maxima: how to distinguish between a row of a matrix and a row vector?

Tags: function, matrix, vector, maxima, wxmaxima

I'd like to build a function that can take a vector (i.e. a 1xm or nx1 matrix) or a column / row of a matrix, as input; however, I've come up on something that seems a bit weird: even though maxima handles vectors as matrices with either 1 row or col, it has different requirements for referring to their elements.

For example:

```
aMatrix:matrix([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);
matrixVec: aMatrix[1];
aVec:matrix([1,2,3]);
```

Now, even though `matrixVec` and `aVec` were a) obtained from the `matrix` function, and have the same dimensions (as determined by `length()` and `length(transpose())`, referencing their elements requires completely different notations:
`matrixVec[1,1];` returns an error;
whereas `aVec[1,1];` returns 1, as expected.

I think I understand *why* this would be; however, because both of these objects return `true` from `matrixp` (and have the same dimensions), I have no idea how to distinguish them in my code, so that I can define proper handling.

**What kind of if statement could I use to distinguish these two so that I can define `value = x[i]` for the matrix and `value = x[1,i]` for the row vector?**

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon a solution while working on something else: it turns out that Maxima treats the row or column of a matrix as a list, although it doesn't treat a row or column vector as a list, i.e. given

```
aMatrix : matrix([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);
matrixVec : aMatrix[1];
aVec : matrix([1,2,3]);
```

`listp(matrixVec)` returns "true" whereas `listp(aVec)` returns "false".

i.e. **`listp()` can be used to distinguish a 1xm or nx1 matrix from the row or column of a matrix.**